# How to combine multiple CouchDB queries into a single request?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to query documents in a Cloudant.com database (CouchDB). The two following query requests work fine separately:

```
{ "selector": { "some_field": "value_1" } }

{ "selector": { "some_field": "value_2" } }
```

Cloudant's documentation seems to indicate I should be able to combine those two queries into a single HTTP request as follows:

```
{ "selector": { "$or": [ { "some_field": "value_1" }, 
                         { "some_field": "value_2" } ] } }
```

But when I try that I receive the following response:

```
{"error":"no_usable_index",
 "reason":"There is no operator in this selector can used with an index."}
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this with Cloudant Query at the moment. However, you can use a view query instead using the index created with Cloudant Query. Assuming the index is in a design document named `ae97413b0892b3738572e05b2101cdd303701bb8`:

```
curl -X POST \
'https://youraccount.cloudant.com/db/_design/ae97413b0892b3738572e05b2101cdd303701bb8/_view/ae97413b0892b3738572e05b2101cdd303701bb8?reduce=false&include_docs=true' \
-d '
{
  "keys":[
    ["value_1"],
    ["value_2"]
  ]
}'
```

This will give you a response like this:

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 1,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "5fcec42ba5cad4fb48a676400dc8f127",
      "key": [
        "abc"
      ],
      "value": null,
      "doc": {
        "_id": "5fcec42ba5cad4fb48a676400dc8f127",
        "_rev": "1-0042bf88a7d830e9fdb0326ae957e3bc",
        "some_field": "value_1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "955606432c9d3aaa48cab0c34dc2a9c8",
      "key": [
        "ghi"
      ],
      "value": null,
      "doc": {
        "_id": "955606432c9d3aaa48cab0c34dc2a9c8",
        "_rev": "1-68fac0c180923a2bf133132301b1c15e",
        "some_field": "value_2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```